# Sci-fi movie from the 1970's or 1980's with a robot in a junk pile salvaging a battery

Tags: story-identification, b-movies

I remember a sci-fi movie when I was a kid (70's-80's) where a robot character fell into a junk pit and scavenged a battery from a similar robot. Does anyone know anything about this movie? I'm sure it was a B movie.

The movie was live action with the robot as a guy in a suit. The battery looked a little like a VHS tape and went into his chest.

Comment: Live action? In English? Actor in a robot suit? Futuristic battery or car battery? Can you give us more details?

Comment: Commenting on the off-chance you're confusing real memories with Turbo Kid, which has this scene and is deliberately styled to look like an 80s movie.

Comment: But for some details, you could well be describing Wall-E

Comment: "Star Odyssey" (1979) has a robot in a junkyard scene where a human man and woman find him and put some kind of battery in his back? It's a really cheesy Italian Star Wars rip-off and is on YouTube.The battery didn't look like a VHS tape though.